# C++ int and char array adress

Tags: c++, arrays

I just started learning C++. I have confusion while printing out the int array it is printing the 0th element address of the array. And (array + 1) is the address after 4 registers since int is 4byte. But for char array, the behavior is not the same. Is char array implemented differently in C++?

code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    char char_array [5] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int int_array [5] {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout << sizeof(char) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << char_array << endl;
    cout << char_array+1 << endl;
    cout << int_array << endl;
    cout << int_array + 1 << endl;
}
```

output:

```
1
4
aeiou≡r
eiou≡r
0x61fe00
0x61fe04

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.428 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters the program has undefined behavior because the declared character array

```
char char_array [5] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
```

does not contain a string but using the overloaded operator << in these statements

```
cout << char_array << endl;
cout << char_array+1 << endl
```

for a pointer to char requires that the pointer would point to a string.

You could at least declare the array like

```
char char_array [6] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0' };
```

Using an integer array as an expression in the operator << results that the overloaded resolution selects the operator for the type void * and the operator outputs the address of the first element of the integer array.

In these statements

```
cout << char_array+1 << endl;
cout << int_array + 1 << endl;
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. The expression char_array+1 or  int_array + 1 increases the value or the pointer (the array designator in such an expression is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element) by the value equal to `sizeof( char )` or sizeof( int ) correspondingly.

`sizeof( char )` is always equal to `1`. `sizeof( int )` depends on the used system and usually at least for 32-bit systems is equal to `4`. And this output

```
0x61fe00
0x61fe04
```

demonstrates this.

If you want to output addresses for elements of the character array then you should write for example

```
cout << static_cast<void *>( char_array ) << endl;
cout << static_cast<void *>( char_array+1 ) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, Vlad, but my intuition was that char_array would print memory address of 'a' and char_array + 1 would print memory address of 'e'

Comment: @Epsi95 In this case you need to write for example cout << static_cast<void *>( char_array ) << endl;

Comment: @Epsi95 In C strings were simply null-terminated char arrays, so there is a special overload of the `<<` operator for char pointers which will print the null-terminated string at the address instead of the address itself.

Comment: @Vlad great now I am getting 0x61fe1a, 0x61fe1b exactly 1 byte. Need to go long way seems :p. Although I am unable to fully understand the reasoning, all I could gather is the overloading operator << is doing something with the char pointer that is why its behavior is different from int pointer.

Comment: @BessieTheCow great, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Epsi95 For a character pointer the overloaded operator << assumes that the pointer points to a string and outputs the pointed string.

Answer (score 1):

`char[5]` gets decayed to `char const *`, and then there is an overload for `operator<<` that writes out the string represented by the `char const *`.

`int[5]` decays to `int const *`, but there is not a similar overload for `int const *`, and so it simply prints the address.

Comment: how about a null terminator? doesnt `cout` expect one?

Comment: It does. In fact, you can see that it tries to print stuff out, hence the weird symbols.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is a variable of type `std::basic_ostream` which has an overload especially for formatting `char*`. Which is important because raw arrays will decay to pointers when passed by value.

The unique overload of `operator<<` for `char*` expects that the incoming data is a C String. Which is a string of characters that is nul terminated.

`char char_array [5] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};`

Creates an array which is not nul terminated which is why you get seemingly random characters (via a buffer over read, leading to undefined behaviour). To rectify that you would just need to include a nul terminator. When `char_array` is declared as :

`char char_array [6] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','\0'};`

then

`std::cout << char_array << std::endl;`

will output `aeiou` and

`std::cout << char_array + 1 << std::endl;`

will output `eiou`

Comment: Thanks, George, but my problem was not that it is printing some random char after "aeiou" as there is no null termination but why I was not getting the memory address.

Comment: @Epsi95 Reading past the end of an array is undefined behavior. You're not guaranteed to get random characters.

Comment: @BessieTheCow yes true, random char is not a proper word, it's undefined value.

Answer (score -1):

Here `int_array` is a pointer to an array of `int`. When you print `int_array`, you are printing the address of the start of the array (`0x61fe00` in you case). When you print `int_array + 1` your are doing what is called pointer arithmetic: `int_array + 1` could be roughly translated as give me the next address holding and `int` and as `int` is 4 bytes, you can see that the next address is effectively the address plus four.

`char_array` is also a pointer to an array of char. Passing a pointer to an array of `char` while effectively print the underlying `string`. Here your string misses the end character `\0' which is UB.

You should definitively read on what is a pointer and a value because it is clear here that you are missing that knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

A `char` array is a string and is being output as one.